# Can you suggest a good xpath for the below scenario?

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

My html code is as below -

```
<table id="tblResults_" class="jtable ui-widget-content">
<thead>
<tbody>
<tr class="jtable-data-row jtable-row-even jtable-row-selected" data-record-key="-1" style="">
<td class="jtable-command-column">
<td class="jtable-command-column">
<td class="jtable-command-column">
<td>-1</td>
<td>** new record **</td>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td/>
<td class="jtable-command-column">
<button class="jtable-command-button jtable-delete-command-button" title="Delete" style="background-color: transparent;">
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

*Scenario to automate :- In a dynamically generated table , i need to add a new data row .Then i need to verify the added data and delete it .*

Currently i folllow the following steps :-
1)verify the row in which data is added . 
2)With reference to the row number , click on the delete button with an xpath as below.

```
xpath=//*[@id='tblResults_']/tbody/tr["+rownumber+"/td[15/button
```

This xpath is working .
But as per the current scenario i need to make the td also flexible.

So i went for the below xpath:-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tblResults_']/tbody/tr/*/button[contains(@title,"Delete")]"));
```

But when i am paste the above code to eclipse it is giving me some error which says left side should be a variable .

Can anyone help me here ?

*Requirements - Row number to be variable . column number should not be considered . button class or title can be considered .*

Comment: I tried the following xpath also . this works in ide , but displays error in eclipse - I am wondering why this happens ..                                             Xpath :- //*[@id='tblResults_']/tbody/tr/td[contains(@class,"jtable-command-column")]/button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to handle quotes properly:

```
"//*[@id='tblResults_']/tbody/tr/*/button[contains(@title, 'Delete')]"
```

Also, if this is always the last `tr` that you need to check:

```
"//*[@id='tblResults_']/tbody/tr[last()]//button[contains(@title, 'Delete')]"
```

Comment: Thanks Alecxe , The below code worked for me :     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='tblResults_']/tbody/tr[" + row
    + "]//button[@title='Delete']")).click();